# How do I take an image uri from <ImagePickerExample.js> and use it in my <WritingPage.js> file?

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, imagepicker, imageuri

My  returns the following.

```
<View style={{photoBoxStyle}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage} >
        {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{alignSelf: 'center',height:200, width:200, marginTop:10}}/>}
        {!image && (
          <Button title="Photo +" onPress={pickImage} />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

In <WritingPage.js> file, I imported ImagePickerExample, and used it. I really want to get uri of the image that I selected inside ImagePickerExample, but the terminal log keeps telling me

> LOG  uri does not exist  LOG
> post/49k8N1vrC2YDsHK5Vn2n7EEpkdG3/0.p60n27ciy4  LOG  uploadImage tried
> LOG  [TypeError: Network request failed]

What should I do? Please help...

<ImagePickerExample.js>

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { TouchableOpacity, Button, Image, View, Platform } from 'react-native';
import * as ImagePicker from 'expo-image-picker';

export default function ImagePickerExample(props) {
  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);
  const [showImagePicker, setShowImagePicker] = useState(false);
  const [photoBoxStyle, setPhotoBoxStyle] = useState({
    width:'90%',
    borderRadius: 10,
    borderColor: 'black',
    borderWidth: 1,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    marginTop: 10,
    height: 40,
  });
  useEffect(() => {
    if (image) {
      setPhotoBoxStyle({
        height: 220,
        width:'90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
      });
    } else {
      setPhotoBoxStyle({
        width:'90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
        height: 40,
      });
    }
  }, [image]);
  const pickImage = async () => {
    // No permissions request is necessary for launching the image library
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchImageLibraryAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.All,
      allowsEditing: true,
      aspect: [4, 3],
      quality: 1,
    });
    
    console.log(result);

    if (!result.canceled) {
      setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
      setShowImagePicker(true);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={{photoBoxStyle}}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={pickImage} >
        {image && <Image source={{ uri: image }} style={{alignSelf: 'center',height:200, width:200, marginTop:10}}/>}
        {!image && (
          <Button title="Photo +" onPress={pickImage} />
        )}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}
```

<WritingPage.js>

```
import {NavigationContainer, useNavigation} from "@react-navigation/native";
import Dell_fill from '../assets/icons/Dell_fill.png'
import Setting_fill from '../assets/icons/Setting_fill.png'
import Lock_fill from '../assets/icons/Lock_fill.png'
import Angry from '../assets/icons/Angry.png'
import Happy from '../assets/icons/Happy.png'
import Sad from '../assets/icons/Sad.png'
import Lol from '../assets/icons/Lol.png'
import Wow from '../assets/icons/Wow.png'
import ImagePickerExample from '../components/ImagePickerExample';
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';
import 'firebase/compat/storage'


//<Image source={{uri:props.route.params.image}}/> is used when I get the image source from the post screen.
function WritingPage(props){
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  const [content, setContent]=useState("")
  const [feeling, setFeeling]=useState("Happy")
  const [readableBy, setReadableBy]=useState("Friends")//should be changed to Myself
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(2);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);

  const handleImagePress = (index) => {
    setActiveIndex(index);
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        setFeeling('Sad');
        break;
      case 1:
        setFeeling('Wow');
        break;
      case 2:
        setFeeling('Happy');
        break;
      case 3:
        setFeeling('Lol');
        break;
      case 4:
        setFeeling('Angry');
        break;
    }
  };

  const handleImageSelected = (imageUri) => {
    console.log('imageUri:'+imageUri)
    setSelectedImage(imageUri);
  };
  
  const uploadImage =async() => {
    try{
      
      const uri = selectedImage;
      if(uri===null){
        console.log('uri does not exist');
      }else{
        console.log('uri does exist');
        console.log('uri:'+uri);
      }
      const childPath = `post/${firebase.auth().currentUser.uid}/${Math.random().toString(36)}`;
      console.log(childPath);
      console.log('uploadImage tried');
      const response = await fetch(uri);

      const blob = await response.blob();
      console.log('response, blob tried');
      //firebase storage에 저장하기
      const task = firebase.storage().ref().child(childPath).put(blob);

      const taskProgress = snapshot =>{
          console.log(`transferred: ${snapshot.bytesTransferred}`)
      }
      const taskCompleted = () =>{
          task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((snapshot) => {
              savePostData(snapshot);
              console.log(snapshot);
          });
      }

      const taskError = snapshot =>{
          console.log(snapshot)
      }

      task.on("state_changed", taskProgress, taskError, taskCompleted)
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  }
  const savePostData=(downloadURL)=>{
      //firestore에 저장하기
      firebase.firestore().collection('posts').doc(firebase.auth().currentUser.uid).collection("UserPosts")
      .add({
          downloadURL,
          content,
          creation: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
          feeling,
          readableBy
      }). then((function () {
        props.navigation.navigate('HomeScreen');
      }))
  }

    return(
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ImageBackground source={m1}
          resizeMode="cover" style={styles.image}
        >
          <View style={styles.frame}>
            <Text style={styles.title}>오늘의 기억</Text>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=> navigation.navigate('HomeScreen')} style={styles.exitButton}>
                <Image source={Dell_fill} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=> navigation.navigate('')} style={styles.button1}>
                <Image source={Setting_fill} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress= {()=> navigation.navigate('')} style={styles.button2}>
                <Image source={Lock_fill} />
            </TouchableOpacity>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.frame2}>
            <Text style={styles.chooseText}>오늘의 표정을 선택해주세요</Text>
            <View style={styles.emoticonBox}>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageButton} onPress={()=>handleImagePress(0)}>
                    <Image source={Sad} style={[styles.margin,{tintColor: activeIndex === 0 ? 'red' : 'black'}]} />
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageButton} onPress={()=>handleImagePress(1)}>
                    <Image source={Wow} style={[styles.margin,{tintColor: activeIndex === 1 ? 'red' : 'black'}]}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageButton} onPress={()=>handleImagePress(2)}>
                    <Image source={Happy} style={[styles.margin,{tintColor: activeIndex === 2 ? 'red' : 'black'}]}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageButton} onPress={()=>handleImagePress(3)}>
                    <Image source={Lol} style={[styles.margin,{tintColor: activeIndex === 3 ? 'red' : 'black'}]}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
                <TouchableOpacity style={styles.imageButton} onPress={()=>handleImagePress(4)}>
                    <Image source={Angry} style={[styles.margin,{tintColor: activeIndex === 4 ? 'red' : 'black'}]}/>
                </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
          </View>
          <View style={styles.frame3}>
            <View>
              <ImagePickerExample onImageSelected={handleImageSelected}/>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.dateBox}>
              <Text style={styles.date}>Date: ...</Text>
            </View>
            <TextInput
              placeholder="Write a Caption . . ."
              onChangeText={(content)=> setContent(content)}
              multiline={true}
            />
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonContainer} onPress={()=>uploadImage()}>
              <Text>Save</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            
          </View>
        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
      // 로그인 페이지로 이동하는 버튼 
      //<Button title="go to main" onPress={()=>navigation.navigate('LogIn')}/>
    );
  };

  const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      buttonContainer:{
        backgroundColor:'white',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
      container:{
        flex:1,
      },
      frame:{
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%',
        borderRadius: 40,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(177,137,176,0.8)',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: "center",  
        position: 'absolute',
        textAlign: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
      },
      frame2:{
        height: '12%',
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#E1BFDF',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        alignSelf: "center",  
        position: 'absolute',
        textAlign: 'center',
        top: 70,
        marginBottom: 10,
      },
      emoticonBox:{
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'space-between',
      },
      frame3:{
        height: '75%',
        width: '90%',
        borderRadius: 30,
        backgroundColor: '#E1BFDF',
        alignSelf: "center",  
        top: '9.4%',
        flexDirection: 'column',
      },
      photoBox:{
        height: 'auto',
        width:'90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: 'black',
        borderWidth: 1,
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginTop: 10,
        minHeight: 40,
      },
      dateBox:{
        height: 25,
        width:'90%',
        borderRadius: 10,
        borderColor: 'red',
        borderWidth: 1,
        marginTop: 10,
        alignSelf: 'center',
      },
      image:{
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
      },
      title:{
        top:24,
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '400',
        position: "absolute",
        left: 30,
      },
      exitButton:{
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#A381A1',
        borderColor: '#6E8D9D',
        borderWidth: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        top: 10,
        right: 10,
        position: 'absolute',
      },
      button1:{
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#A381A1',
        borderColor: '#6E8D9D',
        borderWidth: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        top: 10,
        right: 70,
        position: 'absolute',
      },
      button2:{
        width: 50,
        height: 50,
        backgroundColor: '#A381A1',
        borderColor: '#6E8D9D',
        borderWidth: 2,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center',
        borderRadius: 50,
        top: 10,
        right: 130,
        position: 'absolute',
      },
      describingText:{
        top: '9%',
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '400',
        textAlign: 'center',
        position: "absolute",
      },
      inText: {
        fontSize: 24,
        fontWeight: '400',
      },
      margin: {
          margin: '2%',
      },
      imageButton:{
          backgroundColor:'',
          padding:10,
          alignItems: "center",
      },
      chooseText:{
          textAlign: 'center',
          top: '5%',
          fontSize: 24,
          fontWeight: '400',
      },
      date:{
          textAlign: 'left',
          left: '5%',
          top: '3%',
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: '400'
      }
    });
  
  export default WritingPage;
```

Comment: In your WritingPage you are calling the ImagePickerExample with a prop onImageSelected.  Your next step is to modify the ImagePickerExample code to user this prop!  You’ll call it inside the success case of the pickImage handler.  Something like `props.onImageSelected(result.assets[0].uri);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution

<ImagePickerExample.js>

```
if (!result.canceled) {
  props.onImageSelected(result.assets[0].uri);
  setImage(result.assets[0].uri);
  setShowImagePicker(true);
}
```

#### Explanation

Your two components `WritingPage` and `ImagePickerExample` need to be able to communicate with each other via props.  Here's what you have already which helps you get achieve this (1 & 2), and the one final step that you are missing (3):

1. ☑ `ImagePickerExample` is a child of `WritingPage`
2. ☑ `WritingPage` tells the `ImagePickerExample` what to do when in gets an image.   You defined a defining a handler function `handleImageSelected` and passed it down using a prop `onImageSelected`: `<ImagePickerExample onImageSelected={handleImageSelected}/>`. (parent => child)
3. ☐ `ImagePickerExample` tells the `WritingPage` when it gets an image by calling the `onImageSelected` prop which was set by the parent. (child => parent)

All that is left to do is to call `props.onImageSelected` with the uri (step 3).  You'll do this in the `ImagePickerExample` component, inside the `pickImage` handler, once you've checked that you have a valid result.

Comment: You solved my problem!!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!! You wouldn't know how much I appreciate you right now. I wish you have a wonderful day!!!! Thank you!!!!!!!!!